# Key Level TTL for Hazelcast Map replace function

Tags: hazelcast, hazelcast-imap

I have a requirement where I need to set a key level TTL for my hazelcast Imap backed by an external store.
Now we use `replace(object, object, object)` a way of optimistic locking to update the value in the map.

I am using EntryStore implantation for the external store so that the value is MetadataAware.

What can I do to send TTL along with the value to Hazelcast and EntryStore implementations?

Hazelcast version: 5.2.4

I have two options but confused about both -

1. use `Imap.setTTL`
   Not sure if this triggers MapStore methods though.
2. Use MetadataAwareValue in the `replace` call
   I have my serious doiubts about the feasibility of this.

Answer (score 0):

Assume that you have an EntryStore like this

```java
EntryStore<String, MyRecord> {
  private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(EntryStoreTest.class);

  @Override
  public void store(String key, MetadataAwareValue<MyRecord> value) {
    LOGGER.info("store is called with expiration time {}", 
    value.getExpirationTime());
    ...
  }
  ...
}
```

If you call

```java
 map.put(KEY, value, 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

You are going to see that the expiration time is passed to EntryStore. You will see a log like this

**store is called with expiration time 1695713821941**

When you replace you need to call IMap#setTtl as below

```java
 map.replace(KEY, value, newvalue);
 map.setTtl(KEY, 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Then you will see two logs as below

**store is called with expiration time 9223372036854775807

store is called with expiration time 1695713821982**

The first log is for the replace call. Because replace does not allow a TTL to be passed.
The second log is for the setTtl call. Now you will have your expiration time again

Note : Setting Ttl on the map entry does not trigger EntryStore.
Add a listener to your IMap

```java
IMap<String, MyRecord> map = ...

EntryAdapter<String, MyRecord> stringMyRecordEntryAdapter = new EntryAdapter<>() {
  @Override
  public void entryExpired(EntryEvent<String, MyRecord> event) {
    LOGGER.info("entryExpired {} {}", event.getOldValue(), event.getValue());
  }
};

map.addEntryListener(stringMyRecordEntryAdapter, true);
```

You will see that entry expires but EntryStore#delete is not triggered. I am not sure why it behaves like this though. Probably EntryStore expiration logic is left to implementor